# Why in WebStorm, a folder called 'express' appears in a dimmed color, alongside all it's content?

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I searched all configuration settings, including `.gitignore`, and all WebStorm Preferences and found nothing. When I rename the folder to `express123` it appears normal.

Also, if I create a folder called `express` anywhere in the project, regardless of it's tree location nor deepness, it would also get a dimmed color.

Where could this color configuration be coming from?

Comment: **1)** Please post a screenshot so it clearly shows how it looks / compared to other "normal" folders -- it can give some hints. Use bundled theme for that (either default light or Darcula). **2)** If you are using custom GUI theme (e.g. Material Theme UI that comes with a lot of other tweaks, etc), check the same after disabling that plugin and restarting the IDE (so it uses the bundled one). **3)** If still the same -- try with all custom (not bundled by default) plugins disabled -- it might be one of them.

Comment: **4)** If you are using new UI (2022.3 or EAP builds), state that as well. **5)** What should really be #1 by default -- always state your IDE version and OS -- for certain cases this alone can give quite a few hints.

Comment: I cannot add a screenshot because when trying to edit I get "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later." but here it is - https://snipboard.io/R9ZUud.jpg

Comment: my OS is MacOs monterey 12.4,  WebStorm 2022.2.3 Build #WS-222.4345.14, built on October 5, 2022

Comment: my color theme is Dracula, I tried to change it to to high contrast, still 'express' appears differently

Comment: *"but here it is - snipboard.io/R9ZUud.jpg"* This will work as well. No probs at all (as long as the requested info is provided). Accordingly to the screenshot and [WebStorm Help Page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/file-status-highlights.html#views) -- that color stands for **"Ignored"** (Version Control status). **1)** Can you check in command line (with git client) if that folder is indeed ignored by Git? (sorry, cannot help with the command)

Comment: **2)** Local all `.idea` subfolders (the project specific config is stored here) in your project (in case if you have more than one Content Root or have a subfolder that was previous opened as a project in the IDE) and do a search for `express` in all files in those places. See which one may be referring to exclusion/ignore.

Comment: **3)** You said you have checked all `.gitignore` already. Maybe there are more places/files? Like some parent/global config perhaps? **4)** I'm not doing modern JS development myself/not using Express at all (if that's the one) so cannot say for 100% .. but it might be an IDE-hardcode exclusion (although it's a pretty low chance for this IMO, especially if it's not Express app).

Comment: That's all I could think of right now. My apologies it if all will be wrong ideas.

Answer (score 1):

ok I found it. it's outrages. the cause for the issue was the following line in the root folder's `.gitignore`:

```
# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/
```

it was added by a college who commits a .NET code. I say it is outrages because it appears that letters surround by square bracket mean "OR" relation. in my opinion it compromises the ability to intuitively search `.gitignore` files